# jQuery Countdown Plugin - only show non-zero periods

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown, period, countdowntimer

I'm coding a countdown with jQuery countdown plugin.

I only want it to show active ('non-zero') periods, e.g. instead of

*time left: 0 Days, 0 Hours, 13 Minutes, 20 Seconds*

it should only show

*13 Minutes, 20 Seconds.*

My code is:

```
$('#countdown').countdown({
    expiryUrl:'index.php?show=main', 
    expiryText: 'EXPIRED', 
    until: timeleft, 
    layout:'{d<}{dn} {dl} and {d>}{h<}{hn} {hl}, {h>}{m<}{mnn} {ml}, {m>}{s<}{snn}{sl}{s>}'
});
```

But the problem is that with this code it hides the 'Days' period, but NOT the 'Hours/Minutes'

So currently I get this:

*time left: 0 Hours, 10 Minutes, 27 Seconds*

What do I have to do to hide ALL zero periods?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hiya please see here adding 2 jsfiddle to show you the difference: http://jsfiddle.net/8JJ9B/6/ (Only the seconds will appear **note** this happens when you set `**format**` option of countdown as lower case) **and** http://jsfiddle.net/8JJ9B/4/ (Zero will appear as well because I have format option set as Capital characters) **update** http://jsfiddle.net/cUW4M/

To avoid any non-zero value to appear countdown plugin has a reference called `format:` with `options as lower case character`

**Further** http://keith-wood.name/countdownRef.html#format

> [Quote]**Format** option == ...Use upper-case characters for mandatory periods, or the
>   corresponding lower-case characters for optional periods, i.e. only
>   display if non-zero. Once one optional period is shown, all the ones
>   after that are also shown...[Unquote]

**code**

```
$('#highlightCountdown').countdown({until: 0, format: 'hmS',onTick: highlightLast5});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Tats_innit, yes I could do this with "format", but I want to use "layout". As I wrote, in my example "zero Days" disappears, but not zero Hours/Minutes. Maybe it's a bug?

The documentation http://keith-wood.name/countdownRef.html#layout says:

"If you need to exclude entire sections when the period value is zero and you have specified the period as optional, surround these sections with '{p<}' and '{p>}', where p is the same as above."

Hm, what is meant by "and you have specified the period as optional" ? How can I specify Hours/Minutes as optional?

Comment: @user1377886 hiya cooleos! can you try using one of the jsfiddle and flick it across I might take a look bruv :) <could be a bug> or might be something else; have a nice one, cheers!

Comment: OK, have a look here:
http://jsfiddle.net/8JJ9B/9/
It counts back 100 seconds (1m 40s), it doesn't show DAYS but it shows HOURS, even if they are zero

Comment: Hiya @user1377886 got you bruv- and it seems still evolving check this link: http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html and if you go to **second unorderlist demo** and click show code - you will notice it uses **format** hence to achieve your desired output I made a minor change to the fiddle **here:** jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HjQSF/22/ and Hope this helps! have a nice one, :) cheerios!

Comment: Thank you this works perfectly! So one must combine both format and layout!

Answer (score 0):

Simplified version of @Tats_innit's answer (all the correct info is in the comments and jsfiddles):
Combining both the **format** and **layout** parameters is key.

```
$('#mytimer').countdown({
    until: timerEnd, 
    compact: true,
    format: 'dhMS',
    layout: '{d<}{dn} days {d>}{h<}{hn}{sep}{h>}{m<}{mnn}{sep}{m>}{s<}{snn}{s>}'
});
```

This yields, as appropriate:

**4 days 22:16:01**

**11:12:13**

**06:05**

**00:01**