# countdown is not working jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [Countdown Plugin](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html). I am trying to set a countdown say : Since 06/17/2012 Until 06/18/2012 . For this i tried :

```
 var start = new Date(2012, 06 - 1, 17);
 var  end = new Date(2012, 06 - 1, 18);

 $('div').countdown({ since: start, until: end });
```

But it shows all `( Hours , Mins, Secs ) ( 0 0 0)`. What i am doing wrong?

**EDIT**

It was just a typing mistake but i used `new Date(year , month , Date)` in my code.

Comment: have you run a debug to check the values of start and end before they are passed into your plugin?

Comment: yes and its absolutly correct

Comment: have you tried to reverse it $('div').countdown({ since: end, until: start });

Comment: have you tried giving your div an id and accessing it that way? Like $('#countdown').countdown({ since: start, until: end });

Comment: yes, in my code i am doing the same , but here i posted like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/cUW4M/16/ or http://jsfiddle.net/cUW4M/15/

Please see my previous reply here: [jQuery Countdown Plugin - only show non-zero periods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469714/jquery-countdown-plugin-only-show-non-zero-periods)

Hope this helps,

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://keith-wood.name/js/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
```

**code**

```
var start = new Date(2012, 06 - 1, 17);
 var  end = new Date(2012, 06 - 1, 18);

 $('div').countdown({since: start, until: end }); //until: 0 to get zeros

​
```

Comment: @KingKong Glad I can help! B-)

Answer (score 2):

The Date object works like:

```
new Date(year, month, day);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out , but it was just the typing mistake in question.

Answer (score 1):

The variable name **end** is creating the problem, please change it to something like the below code :-

```
  var start = new Date(17, 06 - 1, 2012);
  var  endDate = new Date(18, 06 - 1, 2012);

  $('div').countdown({ since: start, until: endDate });
```